# Calling a function when a view controller is dismissed (xcode/iOS)

Tags: xcode

I have a main view controller. When a specific button is pressed, I present another view controller. When the second view controller is dismissed, I want to call a function in the main view controller. Originally I thought I could just use the completion handler for presentviewcontroller, but now I'm thinking that is not the way to go. Any tips on how I can accomplish this? I'm pretty new to this, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your main view controller is the second view controller's parent, you can access the method with:

```
[[secondViewController parentViewController] method];
```

Beware -- if you are using a navigation controller, the parent view controller will be the navigation controller.  In this case, you will have to query the navigation controller's stack.

Good luck!